# ASP.NET Identity AddLoginAsync fails - Name/Email X is already taken

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am running into a problem with the default code for adding an external login via ASP.NET Identity.

I have the following code in my Account Controller ExternalLoginConfirmation method:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
   result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

The CreateAsync call returns result.Succeeded==true.  However, when it flows through the AddLoginAsync method, that method returns result.Succeeded==false with the following errors:

```
Name foo@bar.com is already taken.
Email 'foo@bar.com' is already taken.
```

When I look in the aspnetusers table, I see the new row for this user as expected from the CreateUserAsync method.  If AddLoginAsync is supposed to add a login to an existing user, why is it throwing the error like it was expecting the user to not exist?  You cannot call CreateAsync without previously populating UserName and Email in your new user instance.

The only difference between the out-of-the-box Identity setup is I have created a customer ApplicationUser class that uses an int for the Id instead of string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages were a red herring.  Even though this is the default code that MS provides when you create a new web application, the `CreateAsync` call does not update the `user` object as it leads you to believe.  In this case, user.Id is still equal to 0 when it is passed into `AddLoginAsync`, thus while your user has been created, you don't have a current instance of the object.

Changing

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

to

```
var newuser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(newuser);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
   var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
  //do stuff
}
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Sure, you're attempting to create a new user, but never evaluating the result of the user creation.  What happens if the result comes back where Succeeded = false or there's something in the Errors collection?

Answer (score 0):

Check the AspNetUserLogins table.  Specifically the AspNetUserLogins.UserId column to see if there is already an entry there for it.

UserManager.CreateAsync creates an entry in AspNetUsers table.
UserManager.AddLoginAsync creates an entry in AspNetUserLogins (external login mapping by Provider, ProviderKey, and UserId).

AspNetUserLogins.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id

Edit:  I looked at this further.
You already have an account that is using that Email(Azure AD v1)/Name(Azure AD v1)/preferred_username (Azure AD v2) address in the AspNetUsers table so the call in ExternalLoginCallback is setting SignInStatus.Failure when SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false) is called.

Potential causes:

1. Someone has used that email address through local Identity 2.0 registration and there isn't an entry in AspNetUserLogins. Check to see if AspNetUsers.PasswordHash is null for that user.  If its null it came from an external signin.  If it's not the email address was registered locally with a password (external login only passes you a JWT which does not contain a password).
2. Someone has used that email on another Provider (scenario you have a DEV, TEST, PROD Azure AD application registered...TenantId stays the same but the ClientId(web.config name)/ApplicationId(Azure manifest name?) is different.  This will cause the AspNetUserLogins.ProviderKey to not match.  You will have to call UserManager.RemoveLogin then do the AddLogin in ExternalLoginConfirmation.

Answer (score -2):

Are you using an external login provider? If not, you should not be calling AddLoginAsync().

CreateAsync(user) is creating the user record for you in your local environment.  After that, you can optionally log the user in using SignInAsync(), but I don't think you need to call the AddLoginAsync().

Comment: As stated above, this is inside the ExternalLoginConfirmation ActionResult method.  It is only hit if I am using an external login provider, and it happens when the external login provider (in this case Facebook) has already validated the user and passed that info back to me, and now I have prompted for an email address as username to complete the registration process.